# xsd:ComplexType: How to restrict attribute to specific values and a numeric range

Tags: xsd, attributes

I have an attribute that can be either *"apple", "orange", "juice", "milk"* or a number between *0* and *4655*.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done:

```
<xs:simpleType name="IdType">
    <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="apple" />
              <xs:enumeration value="oranje" />
              <xs:enumeration value="milk" />
              <xs:enumeration value="juice" />
              <xs:enumeration value="flour" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="4655"/>
            </xs:restriction>   
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>
```